# what's the difference between the function pointer getting from std::function::target<>() and normal function pointer?

Tags: c++, xcode

The following code is a **signal** implementation copied from APUE with a little modification

```
namespace
{
    using signal_handler = void (*)(int);
    signal_handler signal(sigset_t sig, signal_handler);
}

Signal::signal_handler Signal::signal(sigset_t sig, void (*handler)(int)) 
{
    struct sigaction newAction, oldAction;

    sigemptyset(&newAction.sa_mask);
    newAction.sa_flags = 0;
    newAction.sa_handler = handler;

    if (sig == SIGALRM) 
    {
#ifdef SA_INTERRUPT
        newAction.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
#endif
    }
    else 
    {
        newAction.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
    }

    if (sigaction(sig, &newAction, &oldAction) < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("signal error: cannot set a new signal handler.")

    return oldAction.sa_handler;
}
```

The above code works fine during my test, but I wanted to make it more like a C++ code, so I changed signal_handler alias to

```
using signal_handler = std::function<void (int)>;
```

and also I use

```
newAction.sa_handler = handler.target<void (int)>();
```

to replace

```
newAction.sa_handler = handler;
```

and now there is a problem. I find **newAction.sa_handler** is still NULL after

```
newAction.sa_handler = handler.target<void (int)>();
```

but I don't know why. Anyone can help me explain this? thanks.
Here is my test code:

```
void usr1_handler(int sig) 
{
    std::cout << "SIGUSR1 happens" << std::endl;
}

void Signal::signal_test() 
{
    try 
    {
        Signal::signal(SIGUSR1, usr1_handler);
    } 
    catch (std::runtime_error &err) 
    {
        std::cout << err.what();
        return;
    }

    raise(SIGUSR1);
}
```

Even when using the original code when I run it in Xcode, there is no output. Instead, I run the executable file manually, I can see **SIGUSR1 happens** in the terminal. Why? How can I see the output using Xcode?

Comment: std::function<> is not the same as a function pointer. It's an object which encapsulates some kind of callable (possibly containing state or bound arguments). It is not convertible to a function pointer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i'm talking about the member function target std::function<>, is it return a function pointer?

Comment: Your code will not compile. Please fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer is that [`target()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) is very picky - you must name the type of the target *exactly* to get a pointer to it, otherwise you get a null pointer. When you set your signal to `usr1_handler`, that is a *pointer* to a function (not a function) - its type is `void(*)(int)`, not `void(int)`. So you're simply giving the wrong type to `target()`. If you change:

```
handler.target<void (int)>();
```

to

```
handler.target<void(*)(int)>();
```

that would give you the correct target.

But note what `target()` *actually* returns:

```
template< class T >
T* target();
```

It returns a pointer to the provided type - in this case that would be a `void(**)(int)`. You'd need to dereference that before doing further assignment. Something like:

```
void(**p)(int) = handler.target<void(*)(int)>();
if (!p) {
    // some error handling
}
newAction.sa_handler = *p;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/201440a4a5a91c12).

---

However, the real answer is that this makes little sense to do. `std::function<Sig>` is a type erased callable for the given `Sig` - it can be a pointer to a function, a pointer to a member function, or even a wrapped function object of arbitrary size. It is a very generic solution. But `sigaction` doesn't accept just any kind of generic callable - it accepts *specifically* a `void(*)(int)`.

By creating a signature of:

```
std::function<void(int)> signal(sigset_t sig, std::function<void(int)> );
```

you are creating the illusion that you are allowing any callable! So, I might try to pass something like:

```
struct X {
    void handler(int ) { ... }
};

X x;
signal(SIGUSR1, [&x](int s){ x.handler(s); });
```

That's allowed by your signature - I'm providing a callable that takes an `int`. But that callable isn't convertible to a function pointer, so it's not something that you can pass into `sigaction()`, so this is just erroneous code that can never work - this is a guaranteed runtime failure.

Even worse, I might pass something that is convertible to a function pointer, but may not know that that's what you need, so I give you the wrong thing:

```
// this will not work, since it's not a function pointer
signal(SIGUSR1, [](int s){ std::cout << s; }); 

// but this would have, if only I knew I had to do it
signal(SIGUSR1, +[](int s){ std::cout << s; });
```

Since `sigaction()` limits you to just function pointers, you should limit your interface to it to just function pointers. **Strongly** prefer what you had before. Use the type system to catch errors - only use type erasure when it makes sense.

Comment: thanks, now i know that's not a good design, can you help me solve the second question which about Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Here you a little example that will help you to understand the mechanims.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

void printMyInt(int a)
{
    std::cout << "This is your int " << a;
}

int main()
{
  std::function<void(int)> f = printMyInt;  
  void (*const*foo)(int) = f.target<void(*)(int)>();  

  (*foo)(56);
}
```